# Saving a variable as it is in the memory to a file

Tags: python, dictionary, pickle

I have a dictionary that is 2280 bytes according to

```
sys.getsizeof(myDictionary)
```

when I save it to a file with pickle

```
with open("dictionary.txt", "wb") as fp:   #Pickling
    pickle.dump(myDictionary, fp)
```

it's suddenly about 100KB in size

Is it possible for me to get the exact binary representation of that dictionary and save it to a file?
and later access this file again as a dictionary?

or if it isn't possible, maybe its possible with another programming language? It'd be important to have that file as small as possible

Comment: Any specific reason to use `pickle` over `json.dump`?

Comment: What's in your dictionary?  On my machine, `getsizeof({1: [""]})` is the same as `getsizeof({1: [s]})` where s is some really big string.  The size of the dict may not be related to the size of the dict contents, which will be reflected in the size of the pickle output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.getsizeof) about `sys.getsizeof`:

> Only the memory consumption directly attributed to the object is accounted for, not the memory consumption of objects it refers to.

Well, objects in Python refer to other objects *a lot*, so chances are, `getsizeof` won't help here much.

For example:

```
>>> a = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
>>> sys.getsizeof(a)
240 # WUT
len(pickle.dumps(a))
28 # looks legit
```

Then do:

```
>>> p = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> a['k'] = p
>>> sys.getsizeof(a)
240 # WUT
>>> len(pickle.dumps(a))
51 # looks legit
```

So, the amount of memory this object consumes depends on representation, apparently. If you want to save only the dictionary, well, you'll have to save just a bunch of pointers to basically nowhere (since when you load the saved data they'll be invalid). You can use [this recursive recipe](https://code.activestate.com/recipes/577504/) to find the size of the objects and its contents.

If you want your file be as small as possible, consider compressing the values in the dictionary or use a different data representation.